# Is an algebraic equation is a form of algebraic expression or are they different?

Tags: linear-algebra

The difference between Algebraic expression to algebraic equation is the presence of equal sign. But can we say that an algebraic equation is also  a form of algebraic expression since it also contains variables and terms. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreeably, one can define an algebraic expression as follows:

**Definition:** An algebraic expression is a mathematical expression that consists of variables, numbers and operations, and the value of this expression is allowed to change.

Also, one can define an algebraic equation as follows:

**Definition:** An algebraic equation is a statement that the values of two mathematical expressions are equal, which has one or more variables.

I.e., we can write the set of algebraic equations as
$$\mbox{Set of algebraic equations}=\{\mbox{Algebraic Equations}\}=\{\mbox{Algebraic expression}_1=\mbox{Algebraic expression}_2\}$$
Thus, the answer to your question is **NO** - **by definition**, an algebraic equation is **NOT** a form of an algebraic expression, rather, it is **a statement of equality between two algebraic expressions.**

Comment: What do you mean, "the expression's value of this expression is allowed to change?" Other than that, +1

Comment: @KevinCarlson That was a typo - sorry.